# Give .my.cnf to mysql command line

Tags: mysql, command-line

How to give a specific .my.cnf config file to the mysql command line?

```
$ mysql --my-config=.my.cnf
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The --defaults-file option lets you specify which options file you want to use.  It would be a good idea to give it the full path to your options file.

```
mysql --defaults-file=/home/user/.my.cnf database
```

Comment: --defaults-extra-file is the better option as it will still use any default options.

Comment: For those, like me, wondering how to prevent using any defaults file: there is also a `--no-defaults` option (`--defaults-file=/dev/null` also seems to work).

Answer (score 9):

In here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html it says you can also specify "defaults-extra-file" for additional params. Otherwise it defaults to the various my.cnf (depending on OS).

Answer (score 0):

or set MYSQLD_OPTS variable for whole system (environment file).

```
MYSQLD_OPTS="--defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf"
```